# Suggested Retag/Synonym: team-foundation-service is now visual-studio-online

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The Team Foundation Service has been renamed to Visual Studio Online. I think we should retag the [team-foundation-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/team-foundation-service) as [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online), and arrange for the former to be a synonym of the latter.

Comment: Microsoft has renamed the [Team Foundation Service to Visual Studio Online][1]. when this happened I started retagging questions on the new name, but due to the fact that the older tag already had a lot of questions, the synonym could only be created "teh wrong war round".

Can [Team-foundation-Service] be renamed to [Visual-Studio-Online]? and/or can we switch the direction of the synonym around?


  [1]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnkenn/archive/2013/11/14/goodbye-team-foundation-server-hello-visual-studio-online.aspx