# How to change the primary tag/synonym

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

There is a tag (team-foundation-service) that has a synonym (visual-studio-online).  I'd like to change the relationship around, so instead of VSO being a synonym for TFS, TFS is a synonym for VSO.

In this case Team-Foundation-Service was the original code-name, now that the service is out of beta, the official name is Visual-Studio-Online.

I couldn't figure out where to edit this, or if it's even possible.  I can see where to add new synonyms, or edit the tag wiki, but not how to swap out which is the primary tag.

Comment: This can only be done by an Administrator.

Comment: My question is only a partial-duplicate.  Part of it is a request to change the tag structure, but the more important part is the question about how we can do this ourselves - or if it's even possible.

Comment: We cannot do this ourselves. It is possible.

Comment: We could do it by: Breaking the synonym, retagging enough questions so we have the neccessary rep on the wanted new master / gaining enough rep there with new answers and questions, creating the new synonym. That can only be done by at least 6 users acting in concert, though that evolution will be hard to organize. Better ask a Moderator for help.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help on this? Or shall we try it ourselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this: [Suggested Retag/Synonym: team-foundation-service is now visual-studio-online](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250898/suggested-retag-synonym-team-foundation-service-is-now-visual-studio-online)

You may need to catch a moderator's attention after sufficient discussion has taken place to establish support for the change.

Comment: But how to catch your attention? I think we already had a sufficient discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319591/3001626) (per your suggestion) but we can't reach you for quite a time now in order to unlock the [tag:dataframe] "to rule them all". We would appreciate if you will -  or we can continue discussing it [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75819/gmts) with the rest of the involved guys.

Comment: You already had Martijn's attention at one point there, @David... Anyway, you have mine now. I'll merge everything into dataframe & set up synonyms.

Comment: Thanks! Will be very appreciated.

Comment: @Shog9 And how do you catch a moderator's attention in more general terms? I created [an identical request, but for "odoo" and "openerp" tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312530/retag-synonym-openerp-is-now-odoo-so-the-master-synonym-tag-should-be-odo) two years ago. I see different people finding it and trying to make the post more visible by commenting/editing/voting but this doesn't seem to help.