# Retag/Synonym: [openerp] is now [odoo], so the master synonym tag should be [odoo]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

In 2014 OpenERP was renamed to Odoo. Currently in StackOverflow Odoo is a synonym of OpenERP, but it should be the other way around. The old name should redirect to the new one. So, the master tag should be [odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo) instead of [openerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp)

- [Odoo Announcement](https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/blog/onze-blog-5/post/odoo-the-new-openerp-156)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odoo)

  [image]

Comment: Their announcement: https://www.odoo.com/blog/odoo-news-5/post/odoo-the-new-openerp-156

Comment: Yes, I agree with @ludwik. OpenERP already has been renamed. for this reason, the main tag should be odoo instead of openerp.  Please see the other request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331636/rename-openerp-documentation-to-odoo