# "Anonymous user" is loading the Review Suggested Edits queue with tag changes to old posts

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

During the past couple of hours the "anonymous user" is filling up the Review Suggested Edits queue with numerous

> Replace apache-spark-dataframe (merged with apache-spark-sql) with
>   dataframe.tag

to older posts. Shouldn't this kind of thing be done by someone with enough rep to be able to make the changes without them landing in the queue? Why should we have to use up our quota of review votes (and our time) on something like this?

Is there any way the queue can be "cleaned" of these?

Comment: Yes, it  would be preferable if that is done by someone with 2K of rep. Are these retags even valid / needed?

Comment: @rene I haven't a clue - I don't use this technology. I would have thought this should have been discussed here, in Meta. But I don't follow Meta that closely to know whether the tag changes have been proposed. I've just been using "Skip", but finally used the "Causes harm" option to send a direct message. The queue is so overloaded I've been able to use more than my 20 votes.  I'm surprised someone who's "anonymous" hasn't enough rep...?

Comment: I pinged a mod already to advice on how to proceed.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319590/one-frame-to-rule-them-all-how-to-handle-data-frame-dataframes-mistagging

Comment: I've cleared out the queue... will keep an eye on it... in the mean time I've pinged some staff to see if there's anything they can do if it continues...

Comment: Ah, @JonClements, I wondered, when the queue threw me out and I looked at its stats a few minutes ago, if that's what was going on :-)  Thank you very much for saving our sanity!

Comment: If anyone wants to review the list of rejected suggested edits, install [this userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/RejectedSuggestedEdits.user.js) and go to [/review/suggested-edits/history/rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history/rejected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like "normality" has resumed for the suggested edits queue. All the anonymous edits were rejected and a block has been put in place (thanks Shog!) to prevent further anonymous suggested edits from the locations used. Hopefully that's the end of this particular incident.