# Anonymous user is loading the queue with minor edits in old questions removing the [excel-vba] tag

Tags: discussion, review-queues

There is already a [related Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378631) about that, but I am not really sure if it is the same user who uses a different IP address or whatever.

I noticed that an anonymous user is loading the queue with useless edits removing the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag because of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095) Meta post.

The problem here is that reviewers lose simply their time and their reviews and even sometimes the edits are approved. I have flagged some people for robo-reviews, but that's not enough.

Some suggested edits (there are more for sure, feel free to add):

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23047203
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23049689
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23050187
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23049785
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23580684

Some of them are even defacing!

Comment: I can see the problem with the [third edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23050187), but what's the problem with the other 3?

Comment: Can't really understand where is the problem. Current size of queue is about 100 and only 4 users have used all 40 reviews in it today. Many used only 20. If the queue grows, they will be able to deal with it. Also these edits are not useless. Your flags are likely to be declined.

Comment: @Sanyash I didn't flag the anonymous user, but the users who approved these edits. I went through their review history, added some more bad reviews they did and raised it. As mentioned in the question, these are the only I found; I don't review suggested edits, now, so it is impossible to know if there are more.

Comment: I mean your flags that these reviewer are robo-reviewing are likely to be declined because they aren't. 3 of 4 edits are not bad as Camilo said.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto all of these edits are too minor; some are conflicting with author's intent (1, 2). The 4th leaves important grammar issues. Also, note that burninations/cleanups should be only done from >2kers, so, an anonymous user doing it in old posts is quite suspicious.

Comment: @Sanyash I never flag users for a single bad review. I go through the first page of their review history, select the worse ones and include them in my mod-flag, I am unsure how these mod-flags will be declined and, in any way, one reviewer approved a defacing edit and IMO this should be enough to mention in mod-flag, however, I tend to make mods' life easier instead of saying "Look at their review history for more" :)

Comment: _burninations/cleanups should be only done from >2kers_ why?

Comment: Oh, yes, I told Shog that the tag that should go is excel, not *-vba.

Comment: @Sanyash because they have full edit privileges and they don't load the queue with, most of the times, simple tag edits. See the [burnination FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071). Also, as mentioned, note that the anonymous editor strips important info and deviates from the OP's intent. The edits are completely wrong.