# Rename [visual-studio-online] tag to [vs-team-services] based on product rename

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Microsoft has (again) decided to rename their online version of TFS. The old name, Visual Studio Online has a corresponding tag on Stack Overflow ([visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online)).

[Last time I tried to propagate the rename from `tfservice` to `visual-studio-online`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250898/suggested-retag-synonym-team-foundation-service-is-now-visual-studio-online?rq=1) and that took forever and caused the synonym to be created in the wrong direction.

Is it possible to just have the tag renamed and a tag synonym to be added for the old tag?

## Proposal:

- Rename `visual-studio-online` to `vs-team-services`
- add synonym `visual-studio-online` to `vs-team-services`

### More information

More information here on the source of all truth regarding TFS and Visual Studio Team Services, [Brian Harry's blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bharry/news-from-connect-2015):

> **Visual Studio Online** is now **Visual Studio Team Services**
>
> Try to be clear that it is not a browser based IDE.

And the new https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs:

[image]

Comment: Using `vsts` as the primary tag is a very bad idea. But `visual-studio-team-services` is too long by 2 characters. Do you have any other ideas for a primary tag?

Comment: Also, to point out, `vsts` is already used as a synonym for [tag:visual-studio-team-system].

Comment: Got damnit, MS, I'm getting tired of you renaming sheet every five effing minutes.

Comment: If it was changed I don't think I'd ever find it lol Can we not have both and link them in some way?

Comment: That's what the synonym is about.

Comment: @animuson what's the status on this? Is the above request actionable, or are there parts of it which are currently causing this to not work?

Comment: This is becoming more problematic. People are tagging things as `[vs-team-services]`, `[visual-studio-online]`, or `[visual-studio-team-system]` basically at random.

Comment: @animuson Is there something preventing moderators from taking action on this? If so, what can we do as users?

Comment: Okay, now I'm bumping this question again. It's been almost half a year. Is this something the moderation team can and will address, or is it not?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313873/making-visual-studio-online-a-synonym-of-vs-team-services-fails-as-its-alre

Comment: Hey, if you can spare a minute or two, I'd appreciate [your feedback here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354655/vsts-vs-vs-team-services).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've merged [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) into [vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services) and created a synonym for it. All the old synonyms have also been transferred in the process.

Comment: Any chance you could add [vsts] for [vs-team-services] to be a synonym as well? It used to be a synonym for tfs2005 or vs2005, but no longer appears in the system. The different sub-parts of vs-team-services are tagged [vsts-build], [vsts-package-management], [vsts-release], [vsts-api] etc...

Answer (score 18):

Since there's not a lot of traction on this question, I'm taking action:

- I am slowly but surely eliminating the [visual-studio-team-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-team-system) tag since it is no longer a relic, but is actively causing questions to be mis-tagged and lost. Where it's clear it's in reference to Visual Studio Team Services, I am applying the [vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services) tag. **Update**: This tag is eliminated!
- I am retagging questions with [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) to [vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services). Once we cross a critical mass of questions, we can create a synonym and be done with it. **Update: [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) is now eligible to be a synonym for [vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services).** However, a synonym proposal in the wrong direction ([vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services) -> [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online)) has been proposed already. I downvoted it, but someone else needs to downvote it and create a proposal in the right direction. Additionally, we apparently will need to have the existing synonyms for [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) removed before we can do this.
- I updated the tag wiki for [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) to indicate that it's deprecated and should no longer be used. No one will read that, of course, but hey, I tried!

As a point of feedback, it would be great if the mod team was more responsive. If this is something that can't be done or should be handled by non-moderators by manually retagging every single question, that's fine, but this has been sitting for months due to lack of responses.

Comment: Well, you know the synonym you speak about in point 2 cannot be proposed, ever? First, a mod would have to break the synonyms which are already there...

Comment: @Deduplicator Okay, fine. Let's break them.

Comment: @Deduplicator we've managed to unvote the synonym suggestion. Is this an opportune moment to fix this issue?