# Making [visual-studio-online] a synonym of [vs-team-services] fails as it's already suggested for [tfs-service]

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

I tried proposing [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) to be a synonym for [vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services) to go through the proper channels to get [Rename [visual-studio-online] tag to [vs-team-services] based on product rename](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310569/rename-visual-studio-online-tag-to-vs-team-services-based-on-product-rename) through the community process, but I'm faced with a couple of strange error messages:

When I try to add the [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) synonym, I receive a validation error that the reverse tag request exists for [tfs-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-service), however, that tag has long-since been placed as a synonym under [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online).

[image]

Error when trying to suggest synonym:

[image]

When looking up [tfs-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-service) I end up on the [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) page, where we can't downvote or change the synonym suggestion.

There is no mention of a reverse synonym suggestion (anymore, it was downvoted by the community yesterday, since the relationship would be the-wrong-side-round).

Is this a bug in the tag system? Or do we need to wait for the caches to be cleared for this request to come through as it's supposed to.

Or can a moderator follow through on the previously submitted retag/synonym request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is acting by design. The problem is that the [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) tag already has its own synonyms, and simply adding that tag to another tag as a synonym would result in a path like this:

[tfs-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-service) → [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) → [vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services)

Basically, a synonym pointing to a synonym pointing to a master tag. That is not allowed. One of two things needs to happen:

- A moderator removes all the synonyms from the tag so it can be suggested as a synonym of something else.
- A moderator merges the tags which transfers all the synonyms to the new master tag.

Either way, you need a moderator in order to do anything.