# Why is this meta question not being addressed?

Tags: support, specific-question, moderators

Microsoft renamed a product late last year and [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310569/rename-visual-studio-online-tag-to-vs-team-services-based-on-product-rename/) was posted to address the tag situation. The request is pretty straightforward: Rename Tag X to Tag Y, or simply create a synonym. We (as users) initially couldn't do it because the ratio of questions between the two tags was skewed such that creating a synonym was disallowed. I (manually) retagged several hundred questions to get the ratio to the right spot, then discovered that someone had proposed a synonym in the wrong direction.

A moderator was involved initially, but no action was ever taken to resolve the request. It's not closed, it has a high number of upvotes, but it's just been languishing for months with no clear reason why.

Is there a specific reason why this request is not being addressed by the moderation team? I understand that there are tools in place for users to resolve these sorts of scenarios, but if the case is that the moderation team doesn't want to get involved because those tools exist, *it would be nice to get that feedback on the request in a timely fashion*.

Comment: Problem is that meta posts are really not a good project prioritization/tracking tool.  There aren't a lot of moderators and they are usually busy handling flags, so stuff like this can slip through the cracks.

Comment: Reading through that meta question; it's not clear to me what step you want a moderator to take.  It's somewhat lost in both your question and in the ensuing answer. So, put it simply: what specific action do you want us to take?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thank you for the request for clarification. I will update the question and eliminate ambiguity. To be explicit: [tag:visual-studio-online] should be renamed to [tag:vs-team-services].

Comment: By "this meta question", do you mean... this one? `[tag:recursion]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Now that really *is* a meta-question ;-)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Interesting point, which leads to another question: Are user requests that require moderator intervention slipping through the cracks often enough to warrant the creation of a tool (or the adoption of a third party tool) to help manage them?

Comment: @Dan I have not data to support this, but if that were true, you would see more posts like yours. Most meta posts do not require direct mod intervention, so it easier for the very few that require it to slip through the cracks

Comment: You could always periodically update your answer on that post so it's bumped. Now whether that may be annoying or spammy isn't my call.